# How to group rows by attribute SQL

Tags: sql, grouping

Let's say I have the following relation:

book_id = (1608, 2934, 1608), stock = (10, 20, 30)

which can be produced by the following code:

```
SELECT book_id, stock
FROM editions JOIN stock ON (editions.isbn = stock.isbn);
```

and I want to produce the following relation:

book_id = (1608, 2934), stock = (40, 20), where the two groups of stock of the book 1608 have been added together. How do I do this? I have tried:

```
SELECT book_id, stock
FROM editions JOIN stock ON (editions.isbn = stock.isbn)
GROUP BY book_id;
```

but that doesn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: Not really clear on your question...can you show sample data and output?

Comment: add a `SUM(stock)` instead of `stock` on your second query

Comment: Jason W, I would if I knew how to post tables...

Comment: Mihai has your answer. Your select clause should look like `SELECT book_id, sum(stock)...`

Comment: Thank you Mihai, it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query would fail in most databases, because `stock` is not part of an aggregation function.  (The one database that accepts this non-standard syntax is MySQL.)

You are looking for the `sum()` function.  I would also recommend table aliases:

```
SELECT e.book_id, sum(s.stock)
FROM editions e JOIN
     stock s
     ON e.isbn = s.isbn
GROUP BY e.book_id;
```